# Use Regex to extract file path and save it in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a text file which holds lots of files path *file.txt*:

```
C:\data\AS\WO\AS_WOP_1PPPPPP20070506.bin
C:\data\AS\WO\AS_WOP_1PPPPPP20070606.bin
C:\data\AS\WO\AS_WOP_1PPPPPP20070708.bin
C:\data\AS\WO\AS_WOP_1PPPPPP20070808.bin
...
```

What I did with *Regex* to extract the date from path:

```
import re

textfile = open('file.txt', 'r')
filetext = textfile.read()
textfile.close()

data = []

for line in filetext:
    matches = re.search("AS_[A-Z]{3}_(.{7})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})", line)
    data.append(line)
```

it does not give what I want.

My output should be like this:

```
year    month
2007     05
2007     06
2007     07
2007     08
```

and then save it as **list of lists**:

```
[['2007', '5'], ['2007', '6'], ['2007', '7'], ['2007', '8']]
```

**or** save it as a **Pandas series**.

is there any way with `regex` to get what I want !?

Comment: You say the output isn't what you were expecting, but I don't see that your code produces any output at all.

Comment: `textfile.read()` returns the entire contents of the file as one long string.  The `for line in filetext` loop is looping over each **character**.

Comment: @john-gordon exactly, I got the each character string. and also readline() gives me just the first line again character's string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this using pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.txt',header=None)
df.columns = ['paths']
# pandas string method extract takes a regex
df['paths'].str.extract('(\d{4})(\d{2})')
```

output:

```
       0    1
0   2007    05
1   2007    06
2   2007    07
3   2007    08
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted, Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your regex to this:

```
/(....)(..)..\.bin$/
```

Group 1 will have the year while Group 2 will have the month. I assume that the format is pertaining throughout the file.

Now, `.` represents *any* character and `\.` represents "dot" or literal `.`. `$` means at the *end of the string.*
So, I'm matching `.bin` at the end of the line and leaving out day and just grouping year and month.

Comment: @amit-joki  I didn't get what you mean, I'm a newbie with regex. can you extend and explain your code

Comment: @Milban I'm awful at python, so sorry. Another answer helps in that aspect I guess.